# Wacom Cintiq 21ux Touchstrips Are Assigned To Opposite Button Toggles

Tags: 18.04, wacom

How do I fix the button mapping for Cintiq 21UX touch strip? The button mappings for the touch-strip modes are reversed when mapping the Wacom buttons in the Tablet Settings.

This error causes the LED lights/touch strip modes to correspond to the buttons on the opposite sides of the Cintiq, rather than their correct groupings.

**Update:**

1. This problem does not affect Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon.
2. Does not affect OpenSUSE Leap when using Gnome.
3. Does not affect a fresh install of Fedora 28. Although the version shipped crashes gnome-shell, so it needs to be updated. Updated version has the toggle buttons switched.
4. This problem does affect Ubuntu 18.04

Possible fixes could be to downgrade the libwacom version, and or libinput. I'm still unsure what exactly is the causing the problem.

Could somone guide me into locating the source to the problem?  I would love to compile a fixed version and use the awesome updated graphical button mappings.

Comment: While the modified button mappings in the libwacom file does cause the buttons to toggle each others modes as well as their own, I discovered that they do not do this in the Wacom tablet button mapping gui. They work as intended and would be a correct fix if there was not another process adding confusion to the whole thing. (I cannot find what it is despite searching almost every file). I have a suspicion that it is either libinput or Gnome Shell. Perhaps if I install another desktop environment I can rule out one of these.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This fix only applies to the Ubuntu not running Wayland. It appears that Wayland has the correct button mappings, but using any wacom buttons will crash to login screen. So stay away from that until it is fixed.

To resolve the button mapping for the touch strips, you must download the source file and modify 4 entries relating to strips from the kernel driver for input-wacom. https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/releases

Before you begin, you must first install the prerequisites as outlines here https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

You may need the dependencies as found here https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Building-The-Driver

After downloading the source file, extract the file, and navigate to each file named 'wacom_wac.c' and edit it. In my folder, I see this file in five different folders. Only the last folder was used by my system, but to be safe I changed all of them.

Locate the following code relating to strip1 and strip2.

```
strip1 = ((data[1] & 0x1f) << 8) | data[2];
strip2 = ((data[3] & 0x1f) << 8) | data[4];
```

Swap data[1] and data[3] and swap data[2] and data[4] so it looks like this:

```
strip1 = ((data[3] & 0x1f) << 8) | data[4];
strip2 = ((data[1] & 0x1f) << 8) | data[2];
```

Save the file. Open terminal, and navigate to modified extracted folder.

```
cd '/home/[your username here]/Downloads/[input-wacom file here]'
```

Build and install as outlined in the '...installing-input-wacom-from-source' page:

```
if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
```

Reboot system. Now the Leds/button-toggle should be mapped to the correct touch strips.

Enjoy.